# What happens when pushing variable to dataLayer multiple times

Tags: google-analytics

Lets say for instance I have a web game on a page and the code is set so that every time the player completes a level it pushes the current level to the dataLayer:

```
dataLayer.push({'level': currentLevelNumber});
```

Does this then mean I will be able to create segment in GA to see how many people made it to each level?  i.e. segment1(level = 1), segment2(level = 2) etc..

Also, what are limits of this? GA has a 500 event limit per session.  Is pushing a variable part of this limit or does it have its own limit?

I tried to find this information in documentation but couldn't see it.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, you're trying to report on the levels that your users are on for a particular game.

To do this, you will need to create a user-scoped custom dimension within GA.

Then you would want to push to the datalayer whenever the user moves to another level something like:

```
dataLayer.push({
'level': currentLevelNumber,
'event': 'user-lvl-update',
});
```

Then in GTM, create datalayer variable to capture "level" and create a custom event trigger for the "user-lvl-update" event.

Then in GTM, create a GA tag for the event "Level Update" and configure it normally, but this time, check the "Enable overriding settings" checkbox, under "More settings > Custom Dimensions" click on "Add custom dimension", enter in the index number of the custom dimension you created earlier and for dimension value, put in the variable where you captured level. Trigger this tag using the "user-lvl-update" trigger.
[image]
There is a limit of 500 hits per session. A hit is a pageview, event, etc. whenever you're sending data to GA. Pushing to the datalayer doesn't count towards that